# json file doesn't show the entire data

Tags: python, json

So i am working on a project in which I have to parse the json file and extract points from the json file. I am trying to segregate the x and y coordinates and then append them to a list as you can see below:

```
import json
import os

with open('annotations/20200205-095430-938.json') as json_file:
    m1 = json.load(json_file)

shape = m1["shapes"]

points = shape[0]["points"]
print(points)

xs = []
ys = []

for i,j in points:
    xs.append(i)
    ys.append(j)
```

The output of this file is:

```
[[70.29729729729729, 342.7027027027027], [64.35135135135135, 351.35135135135135], [68.67567567567568, 359.4594594594594], [75.16216216216216, 348.10810810810807], [82.1891891891892, 348.10810810810807], [87.05405405405403, 336.7567567567567], [87.05405405405403, 326.48648648648646], [77.86486486486484, 320.0], [67.05405405405403, 321.6216216216216], [58.40540540540539, 333.5135135135135], [59.486486486486484, 342.16216216216213]]
```

But the json file is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "4.5.6",
  "flags": {},
  "shapes": [
    {
      "label": "anchor",
      "points": [
        [
          70.29729729729729,
          342.7027027027027
        ],
        [
          64.35135135135135,
          351.35135135135135
        ],
        [
          68.67567567567568,
          359.4594594594594
        ],
        [
          75.16216216216216,
          348.10810810810807
        ],
        [
          82.1891891891892,
          348.10810810810807
        ],
        [
          87.05405405405403,
          336.7567567567567
        ],
        [
          87.05405405405403,
          326.48648648648646
        ],
        [
          77.86486486486484,
          320.0
        ],
        [
          67.05405405405403,
          321.6216216216216
        ],
        [
          58.40540540540539,
          333.5135135135135
        ],
        [
          59.486486486486484,
          342.16216216216213
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "polygon",
      "flags": {}
    },
    {
      "label": "anchor",
      "points": [
        [
          35.70270270270271,
          18.37837837837838
        ],
        [
          60.56756756756755,
          15.675675675675675
        ],
        [
          70.29729729729729,
          32.43243243243243
        ],
        [
          59.486486486486484,
          49.729729729729726
        ],
        [
          38.40540540540539,
          49.729729729729726
        ],
        [
          30.29729729729729,
          37.2972972972973
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "polygon",
      "flags": {}
    },
    {
      "label": "anchor",
      "points": [
        [
          244.35135135135135,
          168.64864864864865
        ],
        [
          250.2972972972973,
          183.78378378378378
        ]
      ],
      "group_id": null,
      "shape_type": "circle",
      "flags": {}
    }
  ],
  "imagePath": "..\\jpg_images\\20200205-095430-938.jpg",
 }
```

As you can see, this script doesn't return all the points present in the json file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I would reall appreciate your help.

I have to ask one more thing. I have 128 json files with the same structure as shown above. Is there a way to merge all these files and then extract the x and y coordinates from a single merged json file?

Regards,
Yash Runwal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code contains this:

```
points = shape[0]["points"]
```

this causes you to only print the points in the first shape (ie.: the zero'th shape), while there are many more shapes in the json file.

you could loop over all the shapes in your json, ie.:

```
shapes = m1["shapes"]
for shape in shapes:
    print(shape["points"])
```

(I renamed some variables to make it more readable.)

To range over a series of files, you can use the glob module; eg.: if all input files are named *.json:

```
import glob
import json

json_files = glob.glob('./*.json')

all_shapes = list()

for json_file in json_files:
    with open(json_file, 'r') as infile:
        print("Processing {}".format(json_file))
        m1 = json.load(infile)
        for shape in m1["shapes"]:
            all_shapes.append(shape["points"])

print(all_shapes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try to use your code, I get the following error: 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read''. It is after the line m1 = json.load(json_file)